# Allow Minecraft to Use More CPU

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

A lot of people seem to be having problems with Minecraft using **too much** CPU power. I wish for my Minecraft to use **more** CPU that it does now.

Some Info: I have a dv7 laptop with an i5 quad core 2.4 gHz chip, 6 GB of RAM, and a Radeon HD 6770 graphics card. Basically, this computer is quite the beast. It can play Eve and other high-tech games. But it plays Minecraft **slower** than my brother's computer, which is dual core and equipped with a low-end graphics card. I asked him to open his task manager and found he was using 60%, if not more, of his CPU to play Minecraft, exceeding his performance.

Question: How do I enable my CPU to use all its cores and CPU power on Minecraft?

Comment: What version of the Java Runtime Environment are you using?  How about your brother?  This may be a problem with Minecraft not parallelizing well, but it may also be a problem with your JRE version

Comment: Assuming it's running at normal priority, on high settings, and you don't have much going on in the background while you play: There's nothing you can do.  You can make Minecraft do more with the CPU than it's programmed to do.  If there's actually a problem preventing it from using more system resources we would need more info to help you fix it.

Comment: I have the newest version of the JRE and my brother does too.

Comment: I'm assuming you're running with High Performance in your Power Settings applet?  For laptops, that setting is pretty important as it can and will throttle your CPU (even on Balanced).

Comment: Yes, High Performance is on.

Comment: are your graphics drivers up to date?

Comment: Yes. I have not had to update them. This is a new computer.

Comment: New computer =/= latest drivers.

Comment: That's what I'm like. It crashes and goes slow and it really pisses me off. I even enabled Minecaft to use more RAM using the Java tool in the Control Panel! Nothing works! >:(

Comment: i had a similar problem with my laptop. What fixed it for me was forcing my laptop to use the second graphics card but instead of selecting minecraft.exe i had to select java and javaw.exe

Comment: Are you using Java 7? [People report that Minecraft and Java 7 don't like each other.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81712/launching-minecraft-lags-computer) Try downgrading to Java 6.

Comment: Are you sure Minecraft is using the Radeon and not the integrated GPU? Minecraft doesn't automatically trigger switching to the high-performance GPU on many laptops. If Serge is right, your CPU isn't being used much because the bottleneck is your integrated graphics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**(Unmodded) Minecraft isn't multithreaded, so splitting it across multiple CPUs is not possible.**  However, I am not sure about a mod to allow for this possibility.  There might be other factors you are ruling out.

From what I have found the mod, [OptiFine](https://optifine.net/home), is supposed to split the load across two cores. (Otherwise, Minecraft only uses one)

> OptiFine 1.2.4 Mod adds a lot of options for better looks and
> performance. Doubling the FPS is common. Moves fog away, adds mipmaps,
> chunk loading control (mod CAF), Smooth FPS, brightness control, VSync
> and many other.

Screenshot of Optifine below:
[image]

Comment: I had OptiFine Mod. It doesn't help at all, even makes it a little slower at times.

Comment: "..supposed to.."

Comment: Looks like that's that, then. Minecraft cannot take advantage of your additional cores. Your brother's computer must have more processing power per CPU core than yours. Quad cores don't provide much benefit for most consumer applications.

Comment: Hmmm alright. A shame really. I can't bear knowing his 2-year-old computer is faster than mine. :/

Comment: That's where an i7 or higher family chip would have been better as they will shut down additional cores and overclock a single core if there isn't any usage on those additional cores.

Comment: I see where your going there. Yeah, that would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for my performance issues was using the 64 bit version of the Java runtime. After that was installed Minecraft ran much better.

64-bit Java can be downloaded here: http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

To my understanding, the 64-bit Java runtime only gives Minecraft access to more RAM. Yet this fixed the performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

I installed ThrottleStop and gave Minecraft a higher FID (in my case, 10 instead of 6).

Now Minecraft uses the full 2.5GHz of my processor instead of capping at 800MHz or so. It runs smooth as butter.

A word of warning, however: if you're using a laptops, you *do* want to keep an eye on the heat situation before the computer shuts off on you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked options/video settings? There is an option for "Power saver / Balanced  / Vsync / Max FPS" modes. Setting that to Max FPS might solve your problem.

There is really no way to make Minecraft use your multiple cores more efficiently, because Minecraft doesn't handle multi-threading as well as some other games might. It might even run faster on an older, dual-core CPU such as your brother's.

Also, if installing mods isn't an issue, you could try out [OptiFine](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/249637-123-optifine-hd-b-fps-boost-hd-textures-aa-af-and-more/), which generally helps with low FPS issues (and it also has a ton of other useful features).

Comment: I have Max FPS on. And I had Optifine and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The [Sodium mod](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/sodium), as of Minecraft 1.15.1, makes the graphics engine of Minecraft multithreaded, greatly increasing performance.  JellySquid_, the creator of those mods, also has made some optimization mods for the server side, [Lithium](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/lithium) and [Phosphor](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/phosphor), which also allow singleplayer worlds to run faster.