# Is it possible to run the new Minecraft launcher v1.6.1 in the browser?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I have constantly run into the problem of being unable to run the Minecraft launcher, and the new launcher is no exception. I have tried a number of things including restarting my computer and updating java, but the one thing I've found odd about it is that I run into no problems when using http://www.minecraft.net/play and its web interface. Even when I use the java console version of the launcher I run into the problem. So I've been trying to figure out how the web version works in order to apply the same method to open the new launcher. Here is what launches the old version of the Minecraft launcher:

```
<html>
    <applet code="net.minecraft.Launcher" archive="https://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftDownload/launcher/MinecraftLauncher.jar?v=1367502965000" codebase="/game/" width="854" height="480">
        <param name="separate_jvm" value="true">
        <param name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dsun.awt.noerasebackground=true -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Dsun.java2d.opengl=false -Dsun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false">
        <param name="userName" value="(your username)">
        <param name="latestVersion" value="1367502965000">
        <param name="sessionId" value="(your sessonId)">
        <param name="downloadTicket" value="(your downloadTicket)">
    </applet>
</html>
```

And here is my attempt to create something that launches the new version:

```
<html>
    <applet code="net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap" archive="http://www.minecraft.net/download/minecraft.jar" codebase="/game/" width="854" height="480">
        <param name="separate_jvm" value="true">
        <param name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dsun.awt.noerasebackground=true -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -Dsun.java2d.opengl=false -Dsun.java2d.pmoffscreen=false">
        <param name="userName" value="(your username)">
        <param name="latestVersion" value="1367502965000">
        <param name="sessionId" value="(your sessonId)">
        <param name="downloadTicket" value="(your downloadTicket)">
    </applet>
</html>
```

This clearly doesn't work, and I'm hoping someone can find a way that does, so I can manage to play the new version on this computer.

Comment: Are you asking us to help you get it working in the browser?  Or are you asking if it works natively in the browser.  We can help you with the latter, but if you're looking for code to get it working, that's off-topic here.

Comment: I can't tell you how to fix it, but I can tell you part of what's wrong. For starters, the part of the file that says `archive="http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Minecraft.jar"` is bonkers. Load up that URL in your browser and you'll find that what you're trying to "run" is not any version Minecraft.

Comment: I was trying to run the launcher, but I guess from what you said that I need to actually run what comes after the launcher. I still don't know how to access the current version of that though...

Comment: I'm pointing out that what you're trying to launch is a page of text and images on the Minecraft Wiki that talks about minecraft.jar. You can't "launch" that—it's not the program called "Minecraft".

Comment: Thanks for helping me notice that, I only just realized I was linking to the Minecraft wiki, I changed it to what I meant to be using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to determine with the help of some of my forum friends that Minecraft's source code has been updated so as to not allow it from being played in an applet to prevent some inconspicuous bug whereby people who hadn't payed for the game were able to play it in an applet. This fortunately reinvigorated my efforts to determine what was wrong with playing the regular launcher. I was eventually told by the IRC chat for Minecraft that it was my ESET NOD32 antivirus which was causing the problem, and that I was forced to uninstall it in order to play Minecraft and install a different antivirus. I have elaborated on this in the comment I made below, but my problem is unfortunately not yet resolved. Here is where I posted the bug on the official Mojira bug posting site. https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MCL-887 However as the original problem has been solved I'll simply leave this as the answer.

Comment: Self-answering is perfectly acceptable, since it's still likely to help future visitors to the site.  It's good to know that anti-virus software can prevent Minecraft from working properly.

Comment: I received the answer to try changing or removing my antivirus from the Minecraft IRC, by the way, but am saddened to say that this is not going to wrap this up and I will remove that from the answer, because even after also deleting the Minecraft folder, reinstalling Java, creating a new account to try on, and of course removing my Antivirus, I still have the problem, and the only possible answer the IRC help center can give at this point is to reformat my computer. I'm still looking for answers if they're out there.

Comment: It's not a bug in Minecraft, as the Mojang site says it's a configuration/environmental issue.

Comment: Well, yes, I mean I can get Minecraft to work on another computer of mine, but I don't see why I would have to reformat this computer in order to get it to work on this one. There ought to be a more suitable solution.

Comment: @Ethan Maybe make a question about your actual problem (not being able to run Minecraft) and include all relevant error messages.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'll do that, but just know that I've never actually been able to get any error messages, because it never actually crashes and it never actually logs anything.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** This is not possible. If you want to play Minecraft 1.6.1, then you need to be able to get the new launcher running.

From http://www.minecraft.net/play :

> You are currently playing an older version of Minecraft. In order to play the latest version you need to download the game.

Comment: Could you please try to help get the launcher working for me then? The problem I'm faced with is similar to this one, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81712/launching-minecraft-lags-computer?rq=1 except the game never starts working after lagging up, and switching the JRE6 isn't changing anything.

Comment: @Ethan722 If you are unsatisfied with this answer, as you appear to be from your comment, you should not mark it accepted. Marking an answer as accepted is a way of telling everyone that your problem is solved and you don't need or want any more help.

Comment: @Ethan722 From a technical standpoint, I'm pretty sure the old launcher and the web launcher are the same thing, but you say the old launcher doesn't work either... hmm... I'm not your guy for that one... sorry. I'm really at a loss for what could be the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SevenSidedDie you seem like the person to ask about this. Do you have any answers as to what I should do?

Comment: @Ethan I don't have enough experience with embedding applets in HTML to make it work, only enough to recognise basic errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help then, if you know anyone with such experience please do refer them to this post.